# Reload a View on Orientation Change

Tags: android, screen-orientation

In my Activity I have a View that "depends" from screen orientation. If it's in landscape mode, i use a layout under **layout-large-hand**, but if it's in portrait mode, I use the layouts under the **layouts** folder.
The Activity shows also a Map with some markers and informations.

In my AndroidManifest i have

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

But the activity shows only the layout on portrait mode.

How can I fix this?

EDIT 3/12:

I have a layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

<include
    android:id="@+id/my_view"
    layout="@layout/my_view"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and i want that my_view changes the layout, but map remains with all markers, zoom level, position, ecc ecc...

my_view is visible when i click on a Button created dinamically in the activity.

EDIT 2:

Like SweetWisher ツ says, i was trying to setup a custom behaviour for the views. But when i rotate the device, the map disappear. This is part of my code in the activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    initUI();
}

private void initUI() {
    setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);

    if (mp == null) {
        mp = MapFragment.newInstance();
    }
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.placeholder, mp).commit();

    initUIStuff()
}

private void initUIStuff(){

}



@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    initUI();

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    initGMap();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    initGMap();
}

private void initGMap() {
    if (mp != null  {
        //Initialize Map
    }
}
```

Comment: [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13848525/2591002) and [follow this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13938015/2591002)

Comment: I have tried to follow the guide. I added some informations in the post. But when i click the button, the my_view had the same layout.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your Manifest you're preventing Android from doing default reset of view hierarchy on screen orientation change. You have to manually change your views in `onConfigurationChanged` method and by that I mean inflate your desired layout and replace your old layout with it. If you want to take advantage of Android automatic view hierarchy reset don't use `android:configChanges="orientation"`.

Edit:
Use following code to add map fragment through XML:

```
<fragment
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

You also don't need now 'onConfigurationChange' method so delete it.

Comment: So if i want to use a different layout for a single view if i'm in landscape or portrait mode, i have to manage all the views behaviour? Anyway i tried to remove the 'android:configChanges' tag in the manifest, but i view always the same layout.

Comment: If you'll keep using `android:configChanges` then yes you have to manage all the views manually. Without `android:configChanges` Android OS will do  views stuff for you. I think you can't notice a difference even after removing tag because names of your layout directories are improper. Put your landscape layout in /res/layout-land and your portrait layout in /res/layout.

Comment: Ooooops... the landscape layout's folder was <b>layouts-large-land</b> and not <b>layouts-land</b>. Now it works! But the map is not showing after rotation. See my updated post.

Comment: If you want to add fragment through XML use `android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"` in your fragment tag. It is sufficient to create and add fragment to Activity so don't perform any additional fragment transactions like you do in `initUI()`.

Comment: If i add the fragment though XML, and i rotate the device i got an `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class fragment` on `setContentView(R.layout.my_layout)`.