# Android: Select between layouts of element programmatically

Tags: android, android-layout

For example I'll use Button element, with layout params such margins and alignment. Depend on the run logic this Button can be in 1 of 2 states:

```
<!--State 1: Right orientation-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"/>

<!--State 2: Left orientation-->
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"/>
```

1. Trivial Implementation: Put them both on the `view` and control via `View.Visibility`.
2. Programmatic Implementation:

`//change to right orientation - state 1`

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)myButton.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, 0);  //instead of remove rule which needs api>17...
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, 1);
myButton.setLayoutParams(params);
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams marginParams = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)myButton.getLayoutParams();
marginParams.setMargins(0, 0, 5, 0);  //(left, top, right, bottom)
myButton.requestLayout();
```

The problem: Too much code, and the `setMargins(l,t,r,b)` **is on pixels and not `dp`** - It's a bug... EDIT: [There is a solution for this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309354/formula-px-to-dp-dp-to-px-android).

I wonder if there are implementations using dynamic attach of custom layouts to only 1 code object of `Button`? Is it possible/logic here to use `selector` here?

EDIT- What I'm looking for is something like:

In activity xml there is a button view whom layout params set on some other xml and non "inline". And the button view has this xml as source for it's layout params. However this button has 2 states of layouts (left/right...) and it depends on some logic (not android: ... e.g. state_pressed, some code flow situation). And when this happens, I want to switch layouts. Better if it will be 1 extra xml with selector.

Thanks,

Comment: `setMargins` is in pixels not `dp` is not a bug it is designed as it is. But you can convert your values to dp and apply to layout params http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8309354/formula-px-to-dp-dp-to-px-android

Comment: You right, but still I'm looking for more elegant solution as I described, sure something must be...

Comment: well you stated method 2 to be lengthy, whats wrong with 1st method of Trivial Implementation ?

Comment: I want to learn how to use selection of custom layouts on the run

Comment: see here for switching layouts on orientation change http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848500/replace-layout-on-orientation-change

Comment: thanks, i'm looking for more like define button with custom xml layout and use selctor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one implementation of custom `Button` layout using selector

```
Button btn = new Button(this);
btn.setBackgroundResource(R.layout.btn2);
```

Here is **btn2.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <item android:state_pressed="true"  android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" />   
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal"/> 

</selector>
```

I still don't know if I reached your question

**EDIT**
**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ButtonStyleRight">
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">5dp</item>
</style>
<style name="ButtonStyleLeft">
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
</style>
```

Implementing in xml

```
<Button
    style="@style/ButtonStyleRight" />
```

Programmatically you can apply/load styles like mentioned in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11723881/android-set-view-style-programatically)

Comment: I mean: In activity xml there is a button view whom layout params set on some other xml and non "inline". And the button view has this xml as source for it's layout params. However this button has 2 states of layouts (left/right...) and it depends on some logic (not android: ... e.g. state_pressed, some code flow situation). And when When this happens, I want to switch layouts. Better if it will be 1 extra xml with selector.